# PHP Curl Recaptcha cannot obtain response success property

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

While trying to implement a recaptcha check on form submission I cannot seem to obtain the correct success property of the response. (Server running PHP native 5.3)

```
$data = array(
       'secret' => $secret,
       'response' => $_POST['g_recaptcha'],
       'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($result->success===false) {
    $errorMSG .= "Please complete reCAPTCHA";
    echo $result;
    throw new exception('Gah! We seemed to have encountered an error. Please try again.');
}
```

Even when I check the box the if statement always resolves and runs the echo and throws the exception

```
{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2017-04-24T18:28:48Z", "hostname": "mysite.com" }<br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Gah! We seemed to have encountered an error. Please try again.' in ...process.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in <b>...process.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
```

I also tried using the following

```
$g_result = json_decode($result, true);
if ($g_result->success == false) {
    $errorMSG .= "Please complete reCAPTCHA";
    echo $result;
    throw new exception('Gah! We seemed to have encountered an error. Please try again.');
}
```

which returns

```
<br /> <b>Catchable fatal error</b>: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in <b>mysite.com/test/portfolio/php/process.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
```

Comment: Try to give me print_r($g_result) when using $g_result = json_decode($result, true);

Comment: `Array ( [success] => 1 [challenge_ts] => 2017-04-24T19:16:41Z [hostname] => tedmoke.com ) success`

Is now the only thing echo'ed

Comment: My server seems to be running native PHP 5.3, could this be part of the issue?

Comment: Why are you using triple=? Do you have any specific reason? Try only ==

Comment: I have tried '==' I have also tried !$result->success

Comment: If using json decode with second parameter set to true, you must use $g_result["success"] because you are working witg array, not object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to json_decode result.

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
```

Comment: I've tried that but only receive `<br /> <b>Catchable fatal error</b>: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in <b>mysite.com/test/portfolio/php/process.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />`

Comment: This solved my problem once I updated the server's PHP version from 5.3 to 5.6